# How to check if PID is running in ansible and if not then fail the task?

Tags: ansible, pid

I have ansible playbook which does 3 things:

a) Start up a flask server

b) Waits for 10 seconds for it to start

c) Checks if the PID is running

```
- name: "execute script to start flask"
  shell: nohup python main.py &
  args:
    chdir: /home/ubuntu/flask
    executable: /bin/bash

- pause: seconds=10

- name: "verify that the server has started"
  command: ?????
```

Manually I do this to get PID

`pgrep -f /'main.py'`

Which returns a PID lets say...

`8212`

How do I do step(c) in ansible playbook, and to make sure if PID is not found, task will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not work with pause, it slows down your playbook unnecessarily. You could simply work with the `pids` Ansible-Module and `until`

Pids: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pids_module.html

Loop-Until: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met

Example checking every 5 seconds for 10 retries, if the Pid from `main.py` is not available then, the playbook will fail.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: check the pid of main.py
    pids:
      name: main.py
    register: pid
    until: pid.pids | length > 0
    delay: 5
    retries: 10
  - debug: var=pid
```

Comment: Hmm, good one but I get this error with it. `FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'pid.pids | length > 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (pid.pids | length > 0): 'pid' is undefined"}` - Any idea what it might be? When I see it manually, I can confirm that the process is running by doing: **ps -ef | grep main.py**

Comment: The Pids Ansible-Module is using the Python-Module `psutil` did you installed that one? Can you check if you have it installed on your system?

Comment: I have the following installed on my machine: `psutil     5.7.0` and on the remote server where I am running ansible for.

Comment: I've checked my example and saw i had an error with the key `register`. It has to be on the same level as the `pids`. It's now fixed. Can you check your Playbook?